# Two Virtual Hosts with to disntinct PHP configurations via PHP-FPM on Ubuntu and Apache

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache-2.4, php-fpm

I have to Virtual Hosts on Ubuntu 20.04. One host is test instance and one is production (I know it would be better to have it separate). Now I need to run different php config for test vhost than for production. I know can configure separate fpm pools and assign  them as handlers in vhost config BUT
the question is:

Can I put any php config option in a pool config file?

For example for the test host I want to run Xdebug and different error reporting. On the other hand for the production site I want to have higher memory limits

Comment: Have you read https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php Example #1 ?

Comment: Actually I had. I'm not sure how it is relevant for my usecase. Do you know how I could use that information? There is nothing regarding xdebug either

Comment: Why not use two docker containers to separate them? Or put the test one in a docker container and the production on the server os itself

Comment: I don't have resources to start using Docker. The configuration via virtual hosts and pool config is simple and reliable. It's just a question in which file should I put config like xdebug

Comment: Yes, you can set different configuration settings for each pool as if were the php.ini specific for each.